# ArcGIS: not possible to enable data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

I have ArcGIS version 10.5 and I cannot activate the "Enable Data Driven Pages" check box. It does not allow to make any changes. How can I activate this check box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That checkbox should be enabled if you have at least one featurelayer added to the map.

Comment: I had loaded only rasters and no shapefile. The data driven pages seem to need a shapefile for indexing.

Comment: @yPennylane Exactly, features are needed to define the extent of the map(s)